# When a simple ideal contained in the sum of ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I want to know if a simple ( minimal) ideal of a commutative ring with ideantity is contained in the sum of some ideal we can deduced it is contained in one of them.

Comment: Consider the quotient of k[x,y] by the ideal $(x^2,xy,y^2)$. In that ring, look at the ideals (x), (y) and (x+y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

Take $R=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a\end{bmatrix}\middle|a\in\mathbb R, b\in\mathbb R^2 \right\}$

The ideals generated by $\begin{bmatrix}0&(1,1)\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}0&(0,1)\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&(1,0)\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ are all minimal, and the sum of each pair contains the third, but none of them mutually contain each other.

Comment: This is an adaptation of an idea I've previously used when asked about the property for vector spaces, adapted to work for a ring. Mariano's explanation is a lot smoother approach which I wish would have occurred to me before this one!  I think I'm describing something isomorphic to that...

Comment: Specifically, mapping $x$ to the second matrix and $y$ to the third matrix (from $k[x,y]$) should give rise to the isomorphism with Mariano's example.