# Minimal ideal in commutative finite rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative finite ring with identity, and let $I$ be a minimal ideal of $R$, that is, a non-zero ideal that there is no ideal strictly between $I$ and $0$. Now let $\{I_i\}_{i\in A}$ be a family of ideals of $R$ such that $I\subseteq \sum_{i\in A} I_i$. How can we show that there exists $j\in A$ such that $I\subseteq I_j$? If the statment is not true is there any condition under which it is true?

Comment: Can any one give an example of a minimal ideal which does not satisfy the above property?

Comment: @K.Z the examples given at your previous question about this are trivially modifiable to be finite.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively easy to prove if $R$ is an integral domain. Without loss of generality, we may suppose that $I_j \neq \{0\}$ for all $j\in A$.

Suppose by way of contradiction that $I\not\subseteq I_j$ for any $j\in A$, then by minimality of $I$ it holds that
$$
I\cap I_j = \{0\}, \qquad \forall j\in A
$$
Now, fix $j\in A$ and $r\in I_j\setminus\{0\}$ and note that $rI$ is an ideal contained both in $I$ and in $I_j$. To see that $rI\subseteq I_j$, note that
$$
rI = \{ri \mid i\in I\}= \bigcup_{i\in I} \{r i\} \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} I_j i \subseteq I_j
$$
But then $rI \subseteq I\cap I_j = \{0\}$. In particular, $ri = 0$ for all $i\in I$ which contradicts the assumption that $R$ is an integral domain.

Note that this proof actually shows that $I\subseteq I_j$ for all $j\in A$.

Comment: The question concerns finite rings. Finite commutative integral domains are fields, not much to say about minimal ideals. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mohan No, you're right. I'll leave my answer there just in case someone finds it useful

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to show in general: there are counter examples. For example, from [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2631486/29335), you can adapt the counterexample given to be $F[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ where $F$ is the field of two elements.

If this property held for a particular minimal right ideal $T$, then there could not be any other copies of $T$ in $R$, because you can construct a third copy of $T$ such that the original $T$ is contained in the sum of the second two, but is not equal to them.  So a necessary condition would be for the minimal ideal to be nonisomorphic with all other minimal ideals.

I think it may also be sufficient, but haven’t sat down to think it through on paper yet.

Comment: Is your answer true for only finite rings?

Comment: @K.Z as I commented to you above, this is trivially modified to be finite from a previous infinite example. So no, it does not matter if finite or infinite.

Comment: I cannot understand the last statment in your comment, if it is possible give some hints. (I think it may also be sufficient, but haven’t sat down to think it through on paper yet. )

Comment: I want to know why a minimal ideal that is not isomorphic with all other minimal ideals has  the mentioned property?

Comment: @K.Z If you have two copies of $S$ with intersection 0, then the set of $(s,s)$ is a third copy contained in the sum.

Comment: I mean the convers, that is,  if $I $ is minimal ideal that is nonisomorphic with all other minimal ideals and $I\subseteq \sum_{i\in A} I_i$ where $\{ I_i   \}_{ I \in A}$ is a famity of ideals of $R $, as it mentitled in the original question . How can we show that there exists $j\in A$ such that $I\subseteq I_j$?

Comment: @K.Z  I explained what I said: that it is *necessary*. I have no idea if it is sufficient (which is what the converse would say.)