# special non zero ideals of the ring of continuous functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be the ring of all continuous real valued functions on a completely regular space $X  $,  that is $R:=C (X)$,  and let $0\not=I $ be an ideal of $ R $ and $\{  I_i  \}_{ i\in A   } $ be a family of ideals of $  R $. I am looking for a condition (preferably an equivalent )on $I $ such that if $I\subseteq \sum_{ i\in A   } I_i $ then we can deduced that there exists $j\in A $ such that $I\subseteq I_j $?

> For example minimal ideals have this property.

Comment: Is there a reason your ring is $C(X)$? For example, is there a topological source of the family of ideals?

Comment: Are you looking at closed ideals or ideals? Anyway it is clear that $I$ must be a principal ideal if that property holds. For let $A=I$ and $I_a=\langle a\rangle$ the ideal generated by $a$, it follows that $I=\langle a\rangle$ for some $a$.

Comment: Sometimes this ring does not even have minimal ideals: for example, when $X$ is the whole real line or a closed interval in the real line.  Certainly you don't still think that the statement holds in general [after we gave counterexampes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2631486/29335)

Comment: @ rschwieb: Minimal ideals of the ring of all real contoniuous function have this property.